# Functions imported and constructed by default with Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I checked the imports of one of my C++ projects and it seems to have a lot of imports I did not use anywhere being used in random functions.

[Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W468I.png) (Using Visual Studio 2019)

My questions are:

1) What are all these used for? Why do compilers add these?

2) Is there a way to stop it from adding those? Let me add those myself if need be?

Comment: Were you building in Debug Mode or Release Mode?  What optimizations are set?

Comment: Most of them are the runtime environment for windows to run programs. Most likely you need all of them, so don't bother caring of them

Comment: I am compiling in Release Mode with Debug Info set to No. @RoQuOTriX I dont understand exactly what you mean. The only dependency for running these console programs is the conhost executable, but I have no idea why I would need these functions

Comment: If you use any std related construct, they maybe need them at some time for memory and thread handling e.g.

Comment: Do you have some source where I can read more about it? I'm not even sure what to google. Also, do you know if they can be removed? Just for experimenting

Comment: Kernel32.dll Low-level operating system functions for memory management and resource handling.      The VCRuntime contains code required to initialize and terminate a C/C++ executable. This is to ensure that you can compile, so just ignore it.